# What's wrong in my code?I am new to Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I want to perform INSERTION opertaion using python,Flask and mongoDB.
When I run my code on server it shows "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again". What's wrong in my code.Please help and thnx in advance.

```js
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import pymongo


app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key' 

@app.route('/insert',methods=['POST','GET'])
def enter():
 myclient=pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
 mydb=myclient['student']
 mycol=mydb['knit']
 if request.method=='POST':
  query={'name':request.form['name'],'age':request.form['age'],'city':request.form['city'],'company':request.form['company']}
  x=mycol.insert_one(query)
  print(x)


if __name__=='__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="/insert" required>
    Username:<input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
    City:<input type="text" name="city" required><br>
    Comapny:<input type="text" name="comapny" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as default it uses IP `127.0.0.1` which means it can't be accessed from other computer. You may have to use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)`

Comment: at "0.0.0.0" it's showing     =====        "This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://0.0.0.0/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID"

Comment: I solved issues. thnx mr.  furas

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not returning anything to the browser from your route. There is no response from server to browser if you do not return anything.

The following sample returns the insert.html form on GET requests via `return render_template`, and the form fields in JSON format on POST requests (when you press submit). Make sure the html template ('insert.html) is in a folder 'templates' in the same directory as your flask app.py.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import json


app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key' 

@app.route('/insert',methods=['POST','GET'])
def enter():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('insert.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query={'name':request.form['name'],'age':request.form['age'],'city':request.form['city'],'company':request.form['company']}
        print(query)
        return json.dumps(query)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="/insert" required>
    Username:<input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
    City:<input type="text" name="city" required><br>
    Company:<input type="text" name="company" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I print my mongodb data on  template "success.html" after doing using this...return render_template('success.html',body=x).what should I use to print data  just like 1-body.name(form field which I want to print) or any other way.